# Can I use grafana with a relational database not listed in the supported data source list?

Tags: grafana

I need to show metrics in real time but my metrics are stored in a relational database not supported by the datasources listed here https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/data_source/

Can I somehow provide the JDBC (or other DB driver) to Grafana?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @danielle clearly mentioned, "There is no direct support for JDBC or ODBC currently. You could get this data in time series form and into Grafana if you are prepared to do some programming.

The simple json data source is a generic backend that could make JDBC/ODBC calls to MapD and then transform the data into the right form for Grafana."

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/8739#issuecomment-312118425

Though this comment is a bit old, i'm pretty sure there is no out of the box way to visualize data using JDBC/ODBC, yet.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach can make use of:

- Grafana can access PostgreSQL
- PostgreSQL can transparently display data in other databases as though it was a PostgreSQL table through [Foreign Data Wrappers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers)

Doing it this way, you'd use PostgreSQL to act as a gateway to the data. Depending on the table structure, you might also need to create a view in PG to shape the data to match [Grafana's requirements for PG data source](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/postgres/).